# getting java.io.IOException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException while deploying the application to cloud hub

Tags: cloudhub

Hi Have VPC established between cloudhub and my netwrok and it was fine when i used to deploy the application there .

Suddenly , i have started getting the following error while deploying the application in the same environment .

Cannot update load balancer: java.io.IOException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Rate for operation ChangeResourceRecordSets exceeded (Service: AmazonRoute53; Status Code: 400; Error Code: Throttling; Request ID: c811181f-0887-11e7-873f-5d34219fe6f8)

Can some one let me know whats happening here ?

Answer (score 0):

please refer to this forum post .

https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/60915/getting-javaioioexception-comamazonawsamazonservic.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42780863/aws-route53-rate-for-operation-changeresourcerecordsets-exceeded).

Amazon Route53 has issues since yesterday: (see https://status.aws.amazon.com/ for more info). Creation/update/delete queries are being throttled.