# Rate for operation ChangeResourceRecordSets exceeded

Tags: amazon-route53, limits

I am trying to delete record set in Route 53 console (web interface), but get this error:

> Rate for operation ChangeResourceRecordSets exceeded

I tried deleting the record set via API, but I get the same error. Which limit have I exceeded?

Comment: facing the same issue @Kirill Zhirnov

Comment: same here trying to add. i think it might be a temporary issue

Comment: Haha I'm getting the same issue. I guess it's a problem with AWS.

Comment: Same here.  I guess I'll go to bed and try again in the morning.

Comment: Getting the same issue, as others have said it looks like it's an AWS problem

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have a look at. https://status.aws.amazon.com

At the moment  (Mar 14, 2017 PDT) it displays an error message for Route 53.

> 4:44 PM PDT We are investigating slow propagation of DNS edits to the Route 53 DNS servers. This does not impact queries to existing DNS records.
>
> 5:11 PM PDT We continue to investigate slow propagation of DNS edits to the Route 53 DNS servers. This does not impact queries to existing DNS records.
>
> 6:34 PM PDT We have identified root cause of the slow propagation of DNS edits to the Route 53 DNS servers and are working towards recovery. This does not impact queries to existing DNS records.
>
> 7:40 PM PDT We continue to experience slow propagation times and continue to work towards full recovery. This does not impact queries to existing DNS records.
>
> 10:12 PM PDT We continue to work on resolving the slow propagation times. Requests to the ChangeResourceRecordSets API are currently being throttled. Queries to existing DNS records remain unaffected.
>
> Mar 14, 12:22 AM PDT While changes are propagating, we continue to work through the backlog of pending changes that have accumulated. We expect full recovery to take several more hours. We have also throttled ChangeResourceRecordSets API call. Queries to existing DNS records remain unaffected

As the last statement suggests, they have throttled the calls that can be made for new DNS records.

> Mar 14, 1:40 AM PDT Record changes are slowly propagating, while we work through the backlog of pending changes that have accumulated. We still expect full recovery to take several more hours. We are continuing to throttle ChangeResourceRecordSets API calls. Queries to existing DNS records remain unaffected.
>
> Mar 14, 3:01 AM PDT Record changes are still propagating, while we work through the backlog of pending changes that have accumulated. We expect full recovery to take several more hours. We are continuing to throttle ChangeResourceRecordSets API calls. Queries to existing DNS records remain unaffected.
>
> Mar 14, 4:07 AM PDT All outstanding DNS record changes have completed propagating. ChangeResourceRecordSets API calls are still being throttled. Queries to existing DNS records remain unaffected.
>
> Mar 14, 5:12 AM PDT ChangeResourceRecordSets API calls are still being throttled while we continue to recover. Queries to existing DNS records remain unaffected.
>
> 07:12 AM PDT We continue to throttle some ChangeResourceRecordSets API calls as we make progress towards recovery. Queries to existing DNS records remain unaffected.
>
> 07:53 AM PDT We are continuing to throttle some ChangeResourceRecordSets API calls while we work towards full recovery. Retries for throttled requests should succeed. Queries to existing DNS records remain unaffected.
>
> 10:30 AM PDT We continue to throttle some ChangeResourceRecordSets API calls while we make progress towards recovery. Retries for throttled requests should be successful. Queries to existing DNS records remain unaffected.

It might take some more time until everything has recovered again. There should however be nothing wrong with your account or DNS setup.

Update as of Mar 14 2:54 PM PDT. All throttling of the Route 53 processes has been removed and service has been restored. This incident took about 20 hours.

> Mar 14, 1:11 PM PDT We continue to remove throttling for the ChangeResourceRecordSets API as we continue towards recovery. At this stage, many customers are seeing recovery as DNS updates complete successful. For those customers that are still experiencing throttling, we continue to recommend retrying API requests or making use of change batches http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeResourceRecordSets.html to update multiple DNS records in a single request. Queries to existing DNS records remain unaffected.
>
> Mar 14, 2:54 PM PDT We have removed throttling for the ChangeResourceRecordSets API and are seeing recovery. All DNS update operations are now completing successfully. Queries to existing DNS records were not affected. The issue has been resolved and the service is operating normally.

Comment: This could possibly be because of thousands of users trying to move away from Zerigo and are switching over to Route 53. They are shutting down their DNS service in 30 days (yes, the mail is legit).